# Why is the ShouldShipPage function called multiple times in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Below are the relevant sections of an inno setup script which I found on the net to install an Excel Addin. My question is not related to Excel specifically but rather to how Inno Setup operates. I am having a great deal of difficulty in understanding this. Included are the setup script, the sequence of pages shown when the script is executed, the relevant part of the log file produced  and segments of the code section that are relevant to my question.

Why is the `ShouldSkipPage` function called multiple times as shown by lines 06,07 and 09 of the log?

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ9iK.png)

[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoGX2.png)

[Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNTW3.png)

```
[Setup]  
#ifexist "config.iss"          
  #include "config.iss"  
#else  
  #error config.iss not found. Please copy config-dist/config.dist.iss to config.iss and edit it with your information.  
#endif  
#include "inc/setup.iss"  

[Files]  
; The include file makes adds all .XLA and .XLAM files contained in the  
; SOURCEDIR to the project.  
#include "inc/files-addins.iss"  

; Define any additional files in the custom files.iss file.  
#ifexist "files.iss"  
  #include "files.iss"  
#endif  

[Tasks]  
; We make it optional for users to have the addin activated for use in  
; Excel. In most cases, this will be left enabled by users (everything  
; else does not make sense).  
Name: ActivateAddin; Description: {cm:taskActivate};   

; Define any additional tasks in the custom tasks.iss file.  
#ifexist "tasks.iss"  
  #include "tasks.iss"  
#endif  

[Code]
```

The following are segments of the code included in the Code Section that are relevant to the question

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
    CallName: string;
begin
    CallName := 'InitializeWizard(): ';
    Log(CallName);

    if not IsExcelVersionInstalled(MinExcelVersion, MaxExcelVersion) then
    begin
        Log(CallName+'Excel not installed!');
        CreateOutputMsgPage(wpWelcome, CustomMessage('ExcelNotInstalled'),
        CustomMessage('ExcelNotInstalledCaption'),
        CustomMessage('ExcelNotInstalledExplanation'));
        ExcelNotInstalled := true;
    end;
end;
```

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID:Integer): Boolean;
Begin
  Log('Trace: ' + 'NextButtonClick CurPage ' +  IntToStr(CurPageID));
  result := True;
End.
```

```
{
    This function is called by InnoSetup.
    It determines whether the "Tasks" page of the Wizard
    shall be displayed or not. If Excel is not installed
    on the system, this page will be skipped (returns TRUE).
}
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  log('Trace: ' + 'ShouldSkipPage ' + IntToStr(PageID));
    Result := (PageID = wpSelectTasks) and ExcelNotInstalled;
end;
```

```
{
    This function checks if any version of Excel from "MinVer"
    to "MaxVer" is installed by looking up an Excel-specific
    registry key. It is used in conjunction with a "Check"
    parameter in the [Files] section, and also by the
    InitializeWizard() function below. This can be used to
    install certain files only for specific versions of Excel.
    See Wikipedia for a list of Excel versions.
}
function IsExcelVersionInstalled(MinVer: integer; MaxVer: integer): boolean;
var
    xl: integer;
begin
  log('Trace : ' + 'IsExcelVersionInstalled' + '(' + IntToStr(MinVer) + ',' + IntToStr(MaxVer) + ')')
    for xl := MinVer to MaxVer do
        if RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        'Software\Microsoft\Office\'+IntToStr(xl)+'.0\Excel\Options') then
        begin
            Result := true;
        end;
    Log('IsExcelVersionInstalled('+IntToStr(MinVer)+', '+
        IntToStr(MaxVer)+') returns '+BoolToStr(result));
end;
```

Segment of log produced:

01  2021-04-09 08:25:21.755   InitializeSetup(): Examining command line...
02  2021-04-09 08:25:21.904   InitializeWizard():
03  2021-04-09 08:25:21.921   Trace : IsExcelVersionInstalled(9,16)
04  2021-04-09 08:25:21.962   IsExcelVersionInstalled(9, 16) returns TRUE
05  2021-04-09 08:25:21.983   Trace: NextButtonClick CurPage 1
06  2021-04-09 08:25:22.001   Trace: ShouldSkipPage 9
07  2021-04-09 08:25:22.014   Trace: ShouldSkipPage 9
08  2021-04-09 08:25:23.688   Trace: NextButtonClick CurPage 9
09  2021-04-09 08:25:23.696   Trace: ShouldSkipPage 9
10  2021-04-09 08:25:23.699   Trace: ShouldInstallFile (12,16)
11  2021-04-09 08:25:23.714   Trace : IsExcelVersionInstalled(12,16)
12  2021-04-09 08:25:23.717   IsExcelVersionInstalled(12, 16) returns TRUE
13  2021-04-09 08:25:23.734   GetDestDir(): Trying to find addins folder name
14  2021-04-09 08:25:23.770   GetDestDir(): Found first Addins key: version 16, "AddIns"
15  2021-04-09 08:25:23.802   GetDestDir(): Installing to default Addins folder:   C:\Users\djela\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns

Comment: In the reference provided above, you refer to 'first set of calls' and 'second set of calls'. What is the set of calls being referred to?

Comment: That refers to what OP wrote in the question: *"You will see logged message twice"*.